# Merge columns in Integration Services (SSIS)

Tags: ssis, foreach, merge

In a Data Flow, I have a ADO NET Source which load a table like this:

```
PersonID, Email
1, "john@hotmail.com"
1, "john_job@yahoo.com"
2, "susan@gmail.com"
2, "sus2010@hotmail.com"
```

I need to merge emails from each persons and get a result like this:

```
PersonID, EmailsArray
1, "john@hotmail.com,john_job@yahoo.com"
2, "susan@gmail.com,sus2010@hotmail.com"
```

How to I do it? Using  derived column? a script component? a foreach loop? (in Data Flow doesn't exist). Thanks in advance.

Comment: The desire is to create a delimited list based on the aggregation of a particular field? What is your ADO.NET source querying against? Must we do this in SSIS or would an acceptable answer be providing a source query that does the aggregation itself?

Comment: How much data are you dealing with? My first instinct is to write a function and pull it with a DataFlow (if you really need to use SSIS), but functions can be slow....

Comment: This is a dummy example, I need to do something similar to this but using SSIS, not a sql query (using sql cursors is easy).

Comment: I wouldn't propose a cursor as a TSQL solution except in very special cases. This would not have be classified as one of them.

Comment: OK, anyway, I'm searching a solution using SSIS components, no sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an asynchronous script component with something like the following logic:

1. Sort your data on the ID column.
2. In the script component, declare a variable that keeps track of the previous id, assign it to the ID column of your input buffer at the end of your script.
3. For each row in the input buffer, concatenate the email field to a string variable.
4. Check if the previous ID is equal to the current ID (coming from your input buffer). If it is different, add a row to the output buffer with the previous ID and the concatenated string. Reset the string as empty.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136133.aspx)